# How to get total number of posts in WordPress Rest API?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I want to know the total number of posts in my WordPress web site using rest API, I can see total number of posts in JSON using this..

```
https://www.punjabidharti.com/?json=get_recent_posts
```

the the result is like this..

> {"status":"ok","count":7,"count_total":34470,"pages":4925,"posts"

but when I use rest API to fetch data I can't see total number of posts. This is the URL to fetch data using rest API

```
https://www.punjabidharti.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/
```

is there any way to show total number of posts in rest API too?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible to retrieve the total number of posts using the WordPress REST API.

The total number of posts can be obtained by making a GET request to the /wp/v2/posts endpoint and passing the per_page parameter with a value of 1. (https://www.punjabidharti.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=1)

This will return only one post, but it will also include the `X-WP-Total` and `X-WP-TotalPages` headers in the response, which will give you the total number of posts and the total number of pages, respectively.

The response will include the `X-WP-Total` and `X-WP-TotalPages` headers, which you can use to get the total number of posts and the total number of pages. In your case, your headers will be :

```
X-WP-Total: 34470
X-WP-TotalPages: 4925
```

Comment: there is no X-WP-total and X-WP-TotalPages in my url , please check

Comment: Please see this screen from postman GET query
https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2zx1.png

Comment: Those header are included even if per_page is more than 1. Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can get what you want in the response header

```
X-Wp-Total: 202
X-Wp-Totalpages: 9
```